# Spring boot with JSP, getting exception

Tags: jsp, groovy, spring-boot

I am using JSP for spring boot and when I am trying following code in my jsp, I am getting exception:

```
   <div class="fc-table ctc-fix-111 border-t inner-grid">

        #{if _purchases.isEmpty()}
        <div class="fc-row">
```

So I am getting following exception for this code " #{if _purchases.isEmpty()}"

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/WEB-INF/jsp/subscriptionsTables.jsp (line: 12, column: 10) #{...} is not allowed in template text] with root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/subscriptionsTables.jsp (line: 12, column: 10) #{...} is not allowed in template text
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]

SO is there any way I can use such code in my jsp, DO I need to add any dependencies for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a correct syntax for `if` in JSP. This snippet of code is example of `if` in Thymeleaf.

In JSP you should use `c:if` tag instead:

```
<c:if test="${_purchases.isEmpty()}">
    <div class="fc-row">
    ....


</c:if>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I have following extend statement, hw can I convert it in jsp??  #{extends 'main.html' /}